# How can I rewrite this using C#, but keeping it COM based?

Tags: c#, vbscript, ldap

I have a function that is in a vbs file.

I want a 1:1 copy of the functionality using COM, but want it in a C# console app. Is this possible?

```
Const ADS_GROUP_TYPE_UNIVERSAL_GROUP = &h8
set dso=GetObject("LDAP:")
Set objOU = GetObject("LDAP://ou=Sales,dc=NA,dc=fabrikam,dc=com")
Set objGroup = objOU.Create("Group", "cn=Customers")
objGroup.Put "sAMAccountName", "customers"
objGroup.Put "groupType", ADS_GROUP_TYPE_UNIVERSAL_GROUP
objGroup.SetInfo
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like it's creating a new Group. Checkout the example in this msdn post http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa705900(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but you would need to reference the COM object in the C# project, let VS.NET generate the RCW (runtime callable wrapper) and then call the methods a C# object.  It won't be a 1:1 correlation since some of the object initialization will be slightly different, but it will be close.

On a side note, if you are simply trying to do Active Directory administration, there are better built in objects in C# that could be used.

Comment: I can't use the built in objects because they don't work as expected in real scenario, above is a stripped down version. The script works, and so I need to use COM to save time.

Comment: @JL: I am curious what you see in System.DirectoryServices that don't work as expected in a real scenario? For the provided example, the DirectoryEntry class can do everything you need.

Comment: @FinalizedFrustration - The scenario is complex, cross domain groups. Microsoft Gold Support were called in, and confirmed the COM functionality differs from the Managed Code DirectoryEntry implementation.

Comment: @JL: In that case, you might want to look at the System.DirectoryServices.Protocols namespace. Even though this is nested in System.DirectoryServices, it does not build on any of it's types.  In fact, it bypasses COM-based ADSI calls (basically what System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry does) and pulls straight from the Windows native LDAP library (wldap32.dll)